# Automatically fixing bad indentation (Scheme-Lisp)

Tags: indentation, scheme

Let's say I make this code with bad formatting: is there an emacs command that can automatically fix indentation? I know this question has been asked a few times before, but all the answers I've seen seem very technical (I'm a CS noob).

```
(define (count-until x y list1)

    (define (iter list1 score) 
    (if (eq? (car list1) x)
    (iter (cdr list1) (+ score 1))
    (iter (cdr list1) score)))

    (iter list1 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the whole code (e.g. by pressing <kbd>C-Space</kbd> at the start and using cursor keys to get to the end) and run `indent-region` (bound to <kbd>C-M-\</kbd> in my Emacs).